# Sending a string to a server

Tags: android

I'm stuck couple of days with my app trying to figure out a way to program on the receiving android side.

Basically, my app should send a string  from android device to another device and to do something with that string in the receiving android device.

So, I thought about sending this string from the android device to a server and that server will send that string to the other device ( assuming both devices have my app running in the background ) .

I dont have any idea how to program on the receiving side , I supposed its called client/server programming But im not sure.

I would be glad to hear some advices how to do this thing or even to learn it from a book or a site or something.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you didn't search the internet for it. There's lot of ways to do this like GCM, etc...

Comment: Yes it is called client-server programming, but as it is such a huge topic we can not answer it clearly and I am afraid it might receive downvotes due to broad question. Just Google 'send data to server android' and you will find enough tutorials, Q/As and tips for doing that.

Comment: It's impossible to recommend much without knowing the requirements but why don't you just use Bluetooth if it's communication between 2 Android devices? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: @RTL I've tryied GCM but didnt found anything that can teach me how to use it. I followed the steps on ther site to configured xmL and thats it... they are not explaining how to continue...

Comment: @Setu im just trying to send an equation to another android through my app ... and i want his device to solve it... only client/server programming will be possible?

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak im trying to send the string on a huge distances so bluetooth wont be in that case helpful. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Try making a TCPClient on the Android Device and TCPClient on a .NET server. It's a matter of opening sockets to the correct IP adress and reading/writing data.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak How do you program the receiving side ( client) on TCPClient android device And where can you find .NET server?